# gulp + combine-media-queries: Choose the order

Tags: gulp, less

I'm using Gulp (combine-media-queries) on a LESS project, and it works as expected. However, I needed to add a media query for `max-height` and Gulp always puts `max-height` lower in the order of media queries, so I can override it with a `max-width` without using `!important` or adding more selectors to the CSS. Does anyone know of a way to control the order Gulp spits out media queries or of a gulp task that combines media queries and gives me that control?

I've tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-combine-media-queries and https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-combine-mq so far.

I was able to manipulate the order by changing:
`@media (max-height:900px){}` to `@media (min-width:1024px) and (max-height:900px){}` but that just feels like a hacky solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create mixin in LESS and then for that Class or Id just use created mixin and property which you want to change. etc

```
.RoundBorders {
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

#menu {
  color: gray;
  .RoundBorders;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how that effects the order in which `gulp-combine-media-queries` exports the css. Can you provide more information?

Comment: Just change color with your property max-height and you ll see how it works :)

Comment: I'm not sure we are talking about the same thing. I'm talking about `max-height` in `media queries`, not just in CSS.

Comment: Aha, I see what are you talking about and I have not used gulp with media queries ...